# What's the difference between `cursorWordPartStartLeft` and `cursorWordPartLeft`?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-keybinding

Tried both, seem to be doing the same thing, could anyone point out the difference?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/53497 Subword navigation : Confusing keybinding name

In short, there is no difference but the `start` versions were there first when the similar non-start versions were added later (because the `start` part was confusing and didn't add anything to the meaning).  It seems the `start` versions were kept for backwards compatibility.